# Install Live Mesh on Windows 2003 Server x64

Tags: 64-bit, installation, windows-server-2003, windows-live-mesh

Is it possible to install Live Mesh on Windows 2003 x64?

I just tried with the 64-bit Vista setup file and get "The installation package is not supported by this product type".

If I try the 32-bit version, I get "Please use the correct setup program for you processor."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might be able to update this answer later with more detailed steps, but here's a general overview of what you need to do to get it installed.

1. Run the 64-bit LiveMesh setup executable again until you get the error message. Leave this window open.
2. There should be an AppData\Local\Microsoft\LiveMesh\Setup directory -- copy of the contents of this folder to another location. (There should be an MSI file at least.)
3. Close the LiveMesh setup.
4. Install either Orca from the Microsoft Windows SDK (instructions [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/255905)) or [InstEd It!](http://www.instedit.com/) (I haven't used this before, but it should do the job also).
5. Open the LiveMesh MSI file in Orca or InstEd It! and edit the LaunchCondition restriction to allow for install in Windows Server (see an example [here](http://geekzine.org/2009/03/14/making-the-iphone-work-in-xp-x64/)).

Again, just an overview -- if I get a chance I'll try and put exact info for your specific case. And, of course, note that Microsoft may have a very good reason to not supported on Windows Server, so this is definitely at your own risk.

Comment: I ended up not going with Windows 2003. If anyone tries this out, please leave a comment on your experience.

Answer (score 1):

Officially No.

Althought Live Mesh will install on Windows Server 2008 because of the Vista Codebase, Live Mesh is focussed at Desktop Operating Systems only. Although it is common for Developers and IT professionals to run Server as a Desktop OS, most users of LiveMesh as far as Microsoft's target is concerend will be end-users running Windows 7 or MacOSX.